# Efficient way to calculate pairwise distances in a big dataset

Tags: python, bigdata, python-multiprocessing, scipy-optimize

I have a big NumPy array (10million x 200) size, and I want to calculate the pairwise distances and get the closest 100 pairs.
Currently, I am using pdist from scipy lib, but after 50000 rows the RAM is full.
The number of pair combinations are n*(n-1)/2,  so in the case of 10million rows, I am getting around 10^13 combinations. With psidt, this is not possible with 32GB RAM.
What is the most efficient way to solve this problem (using chunks, or multiprocessing, spark, writing a loop and calculating distances)?

Thank you in advance!

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist

mx = np.random.rand(500,200)
dist = pdist(mx)

n=100
idx = np.argpartition(dist,-n)[-n:]
indxes = idx[np.argsort((-dist)[idx])]
```

Comment: I think you got it right. With 200 dimensions, I don't see any approach better than using chunks and/or parallelization. Sklearn provides a convenience function  [`pairwise_distances_chunked`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances_chunked.html#sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances_chunked) that could be useful.

Comment: Thanks @hilberts_drinking_problem for your reply. What about if i want to calculate not distance, but apply some other function? Could you show some example of implementation? Thanks

Comment: What kind of function do you have in mind? You might want to update the question to reflect what you are trying to do. Chances are, it will help you get better answers.

Comment: Let's say, cosine distance, or smth else. I am just trying to get the chunks so all the pairs (combinations) will be present and then apply some function.

Comment: You don't need to store all the pairwise distances or functions. You can start by implementing a [heap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html) with length 100 so that at any point only the 100 closest pairs are stored.

If the speed is unacceptable I was thinking multiprocessing. But you'll have to check if heapq is thread/process safe. If it's not, I was thinking dumping 100 closest points from each process in a file and then aggregating them later. But you have to convince yourself that the way you chunk the problem guarantees that the 100 global minima are in these outputs.

Comment: thanks @xan 
what about pyspark? can it be useful for this problem? I am just starting to dive into big data problems)

Comment: What is the dimensionality of the points?  3D?  2D?  200D?

Comment: @NairB I'm not sure if there is a directly available API that will calculate it, but you can always roll out your own using dot product. Yes it can be useful since Spark will handle disk spillover and parallelism if implemented properly. But 1E13 doubles takes around ~80 TB space so I'd advice against storing all pairwise distances.

Comment: @Richard, data looks like as in the example. 2D NumPy array with numbers

Comment: Another thing to consider - do you need an exact answer? If not, you might want to look into approximate algorithms for nearest neighbor search such as locality sensitive hashing.